# connect my webapi with parse server using identityserver

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, identityserver3, parse-server

I have a Asp.Net WebApi that provide some native and javascript platforms with its data.

I have identityserver3 as the authentication/authorization module for this WebApi.

For example i used implicit flow in the communcation between my WebApi and It's native clients.

Now I want to integrate this WebApi system with Facebook Parse server system.

so for example:

If there is a user already in the parse server database and login to my identityserver, i can initiate requests from my WebApi to the Parse server and return data to it.

I know that parse using oAuth2 and OpenId too but what is the required steps for that, or what is the best approach for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have hard time understanding your question. So my answer may not be what you want, but please send me more details if what I said doesn't make sense.

Register your Web API with Parse server as a client. With the client ID and client secret you get from Parse server for your API, you can make calls to Parse by obtaining an access_token with client credentials flow. Now, use that token from your API to call Parse to see if the user exists. If the user exists, then use that user details, token along with the data you want to post to make a request to Parse server to update the data.

Thank you,
Soma.

Comment: Its great a great description but my main problem that i have another .Net system for authenticating users using an open source software called identity server 3 (you can search for it on github) so now i having two system: 
1- System using .Net technologies and having its own users - this system using identityserver3 to authenticate users using OAuth2 and OpenID (Implicit flow)
2- The second system is parse
So what is the correct way to integrate the two system with each others
so any user login for system 1 can be verified on system 2 or vise versa (some thing like single sign on)

Comment: Basically, one of these systems (Identity server or Parse server) has to act as the Security Token Service (STS) and all the system will use that as Identity provider. So, either Parse server has to trust Identity server or Identity Server has to trust Parse server as STS.

Comment: The idea of STS is to have a centralized solution for identity. That system should have all the users information. So, the system that you choose as STS has to main records of all the users in your system. Please let me know if you have any questions.